# In App or Paypal integration with iPhone App

Tags: iphone, paypal, in-app-purchase, paypal-sandbox

I am developing an iphone app and it demands me to sell some real world products with it. I know that guidelines of Apple would not permit me to sell them through In App purchase functionality, So for now i am concentrating more on paypal integrated way. Still, i have ambiguities in mind whether it would be appropriate way or not because i have gone through several forums which says that apple reject such applications. Any input on it would be great help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

An iOS application I developed offers 2 payment methods instead of in-app purchasing (also for real world goods). This application has been accepted and has been in the iTunes Store for a few months now.

The way it works is that the application sends you to a mobile-optimized website (opened in Mobile Safari). After payment, the mobile-optimized website shows the app icon + special link "application_name://command", when tapped the application relaunches and uses the "command" text to update some local data & showing a "Thank you for your payment" screen.

Further reading:
http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html